# UIImage in UIImageView either too small or too big

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, image-resizing

I have a png of a green bar with the background removed.

Whenever I use aspect fit, center, or even fill to fit - the green bar is either too small or too big. **Is there an easy, automatic way of resizing** the bar to simply be 84 px high?

I have been able to manually resize it, but this seems clunky. And if I ever wanted to replace the image, *I would have to resize it all over again*!

```
cell.rightIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greenbar.png"];
CGSize rightnewSize = CGSizeMake(300, 300);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rightnewSize);
[cell.rightIcon.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(7.5, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
cell.rightIcon.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The fits look like shown below.
Aspect fill:

[image]

Center

[image]

Scale to fill:

[image]

Comment: How big is the image compared to the bar, is there transparent image around the edges?

Comment: Cmd+'=' is a very helpful keyboard shortcut. Not sure it's what you're looking for though.

Comment: I don't think there is a transparent  image around the edge. I though everything but the bar was removed... The image is 1200 × 1200 pixels. The UIImageView is 25 x 85.

Comment: @Stavash what does Cmd+'=' do?

Comment: In interface builder, when you're editing an image - it resizes it to the original file size.